# What does '#define xxx' (with no value!) do, contrasted to '#define xxx yyy' (with value)?

Tags: c++, macros, c-preprocessor

`#define <text> <substitute>` defines a macro. But what about `#define <text>`, and that's it? What does that do? For example in the context of header guards.

Comment: For close-voters: right, that a basic question, probably easily found in tutorials.. but still, isn't that a valid question? Let me just fix  the title

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It also defines a macro, to be substituted with nothing.

> For example in the context of header guards.

In that case, we only need to know whether the guard macro has been defined - we can check that with `#ifdef` or `#ifndef`. It doesn't need to be defined to anything, so we don't usually bother with anything. This gives the usual form of the guard

```
#ifndef HEADER_H    // check whether it's defined, skip to "endif" if so
#define HEADER_H    // define it; doesn't need to contain anything

// header contents

#endif              // skip to here (end of header) if already defined
```

so that including it once will include the contents and define the macro; including it a second time would harmlessly skip the contents, rather than duplicating them and (probably) leading to errors.

Answer (score 3):

This type of macro substitutes nothing.

```
#define FOO
```

It's useful when the macro is only used to test if it exists:

```
#ifdef FOO
```

or

```
#if defined(FOO)
```

Answer (score 2):

It defines the specified identifier to literally **nothing**. Simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

It defines an *empty* macro. When that macro word is encountered in the code it will be replaced with nothing.

This is not entirely useless, since the macro can still be detected with `#ifdef`. It's often used to provide optional compilation of different pieces of code.

When used as an include guard (using `#ifndef`) it prevents the header from being processed more than once in a single source file.